# How to get a tkinter window to display in Linux

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

I am trying to follow along in the book Python Programming for Kids.  I am working with a group of neighborhood kids and to reduce the cost we are using the Raspberry Pi as our computer.  I am a Windows guy and the GUI builder of choice for me is WxPython.  I am trying to get ready for next weeks class and have run into a problem.  I have entered the code below

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
btn = Button(tk,text = 'click me')
btn.pack()
```

according to the book the second line is supposed to create a window (frame I think in the Wx world) and the third line defines a button object and the fourth inserts it in the window.

However, this is not working - the tk window is not displayed nor is there a button on the screen and I have not been able to figure out why.  tkinter is imported and the tk object has lots of methods/properties visible when I type dir(tk) so I know that we have tkinter on the Pi's.

Again, after entering this code nothing visible happens.  I deleted the code relating to creating the button and still nothing happens so I am not sure where to start diagnosing the issue I have Googled for information and found nothing useful

Any insight would be appreciated.

I did ask this question on superuser but there is no Tkinter tag so . . .

humm do I need a

```
tk.pack()
```

statement - I will report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need `tk.pack()`. What you *do* need is start the event loop. The event loop, as it's name suggests, is a loop that processes events. Everything in Tkinter happens as a response an event, including the actual drawing of a widget or window on the screen.

As the last line in your file, add the following:

```
tk.mainloop()
```

I encourage you to *not* do the import the way you are doing. I know a lot of tkinter tutorials do it that way, but it's a bad thing to do. Instead, do it like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(root, text='click me')
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

It requires typing three extra characters for every widget, but in exchange you get code that is easier to maintain over time.

[PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the official python style guide, and it explicitly recommends against wildcard imports:

> Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided, as they
>   make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing
>   both readers and many automated tools. There is one defensible use
>   case for a wildcard import, which is to republish an internal
>   interface as part of a public API (for example, overwriting a pure
>   Python implementation of an interface with the definitions from an
>   optional accelerator module and exactly which definitions will be
>   overwritten isn't known in advance).

See http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Comment: Thanks I will try it in the morning.  Your explanation makes sense - you are correct I was just keying in the code from the tutorial.